# Python: calculate an area within an irregular contour line

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to calculate the Area inside a contour line in python 2.7. It is an irregular area as the follows:

[image: contour_line]

Basically, I have the path of the contour saved in the following path, and I load it:

```
AoI_saved=np.load('C:\Users\Roberta\Desktop\Analysis\Pilot2\AoI\AoI_Lev1_'+pict[:-4]+'.npy')
```

I can have one, two or more contour saved in the same file. For each area defined by a contour line I have to calculate the area. I never did something like this so I tried to follow some tutorials without any success. I tried the follow:

```
n_AoI = len(AoI_saved)
for aa in range(n_AoI):
    path = (AoI_saved[0][aa].vertices[:,0],AoI_saved[0][aa].vertices[:,1])
    print path
    area = cv2.contourArea(path)
    print area
```

Here the output of the path:

```
(array([ 731.        ,  732.        ,  733.        , ...,  730.        ,
    730.07987317,  731.        ]), array([ 445.94074347,  445.88346572,  445.83340569, ...,  446.0051031 ,
    446.        ,  445.94074347]))
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e982ceaa0723> in <module>()
    170             coord = np.array(zip(path[0], path[1]))
    171 
--> 172             area = cv2.contourArea(path)
    173             print area
    174 

TypeError: contour is not a numerical tuple
```

I tried to change the code as follow:

```
n_AoI = len(AoI_saved)
for aa in range(n_AoI):
    path = (AoI_saved[0][aa].vertices[:,0],AoI_saved[0][aa].vertices[:,1])
    coord = np.array(zip(path[0], path[1]))
    print coord    
    area = cv2.contourArea(coord)
    print area
```

Coord output:

```
[[[ 731.          445.94074347]
  [ 732.          445.88346572]
  [ 733.          445.83340569]
  ..., 
  [ 730.          446.0051031 ]
  [ 730.07987317  446.        ]
  [ 731.          445.94074347]]]
```

Here the new error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-354ae41b1566> in <module>()
    170             coord = np.array(zip(path[0], path[1]))
    171 
--> 172             area = cv2.contourArea(coord)
    173             print area
    174 

error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1904: error: (-215) contour.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (contour.depth() == CV_32F || contour.depth() == CV_32S) in function cv::contourArea
```

One of my problems is that it is not really clear to me what argument  `cv2.contourArea` takes?

What is the easiest way to calculate the shape of the Area?

Comment: If it is not mandatory to use openCV you could use shapely. It is pretty easy, you create a geometry and you have an `area` attribute for the geometry: http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html

Comment: No, it is not mandatory. I will try with this method, too! Thank you!

Comment: I took a look at this method! It is not clear to me on what kind of data you can use 'area'. I saw a lot of examples with regulat polygons where I can pass the vertices or some points. In my case I have always an irregular figure. Can you help me?

Comment: I added an answer with a minimum working example

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the datatype to `np.float32` for opencv to calculate the contour area:

```
cv2.contourArea(np.array(path).T.astype(np.float32))
```

`path` refers to the coordinates of a single path, similar to the code in your question. Note that I here assume that you have the data in the format `((x1, x2, ...), (y1, y2, ...))`. If you have the more common format of `((x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...)` the above code works if you remove the transpose `.T`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! Just to be sure; 'data' here is the path of my data, doesn't it? I ask because it seems that the results I get are really big even if the area is not really big.

Comment: `path` (formerly `data`) refers to the coordinates of a single path, similar to the code in your question. Note that I here assume that you have the data in the format `((x1, x2, ...), (y1, y2, ...))`. If you have the more common format of `((x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...)` the above code works if you remove the transpose `.T`.

Answer (score 0):

A working example using shapely to calculate areas of a polygon:

```
from shapely import geometry

# a square
poly = geometry.Polygon(((0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)))

print(poly.area)
```

The previous code will print:

```
1.0
```

That it is the unitless area of the polygon.