# Identify region of image python

Tags: python, image-processing, cluster-analysis, detection, area

I have a [microscopy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eArP.jpg) and need to calculate the area shown in red. The idea is to build a function that returns the area inside the red line on the right photo (float value, X mm²).

Since I have almost no experience in image processing, I don't know how to approach this (maybe silly) problem and so I'm looking for help. Other image examples are pretty similar with just 1 aglomerated "interest area" close to the center.

I'm comfortable coding in python and have used the software ImageJ for some time.

Any python package, software, bibliography, etc. should help.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The example in red I made manually just to make people understand what I want. Detecting the "interest area" must be done inside the code.

Comment: Library recommendations or general program design help aren't the point of this site, this site is just to get help with code you've already written.

Comment: Is it a secret what it is? Are the lines always vertical? Or could they be at a different angle? Do you have any other examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canny, morphological transformation and contours can provide a decent result.

Although it might need some fine-tuning depending on the input images.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 


# Change this with your filename
image = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# You can fine-tune this, or try with simple threshold
canny = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 580)  

# Morphological Transformations
se = np.ones((7,7), dtype='uint8')
image_close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image_close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Create black canvas to draw area on
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)

biggest_contour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(mask, biggest_contour, -1, 255, -1)

area = cv2.contourArea(biggest_contour)

print(f"Total area image: {image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]} pixels")
print(f"Total area contour: {area} pixels")

cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv2.imshow('img', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Draw the contour on the original image for demonstration purposes
original = cv2.imread('test.png')
cv2.drawContours(original, biggest_contour, -1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', original)
cv2.imshow('result', original)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The code produces the following output:

```
Total area image: 332628 pixels
Total area contour: 85894.5 pixels
```

Only thing left to do is convert the pixels to your preferred measurement.

Two images for demonstration below.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVkdD.png)

[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dov4j.png)

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was searching for, now will change parameters to fit my needs. Thanks, @neatconda!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this topic, but it seems like a very similar question to this one, which has what look like two great answers:

[Python: calculate an area within an irregular contour line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681563/python-calculate-an-area-within-an-irregular-contour-line)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem and main difference being that in my case I don't have the contour line, I would need to identify and create it. The example in red I made manually just to make people understand what I want, will update the question for clarification.